# Can not get where-object & -gt to work together

Tags: powershell

I'm simply trying to filter out the variables of the "PeakWorkingSetSize" process so that the output will ONLY be greater than 5000. No matter what combination I try, the numbers won't filter. Please help.

```
get-wmiobject -class Win32_Process | where-object {$_.PeakWorkingSetSize -gt "5000"} | format-table -auto
```

***FIXED thanks to @Matt!***

I actually still don't know what the problem was. XD
Here is the code that works:

```
get-wmiobject -class Win32_Process | where-object {$_.PeakWorkingSetSize -gt "5000" | format-table -property Name,PeakWorkingSetSize -auto
```

Comment: Don't compare apples and oranges. Remove the `"` from `5000`

Comment: ^ Still doesn't work.

Comment: Your command works fine for me exactly as it is written. What version of PS are you running?

Comment: I'm using PowerShell 4.0 on Windows 8.1. The command is accepted, but it won't filter the numbers.

Comment: I'm running the exact same version of PS and Windows. I was able to filter just fine. I even went so far as to do `$_.PeakWorkingSetSize -gt "5000" -and $_.PeakWorkingSetSize -lt 10000` and it worked just as expected. Maybe try closing PowerShell and re-launching? Or maybe use `Get-Process` instead?

Comment: This should just work regardless of the quotes. PowerShell will attempt to convert the RHS to the same type as LHS in order to do the comparison. "5000" converts to int just fine. Can you show us an non working example of your output.

Comment: You should `select-object` the properties you want to see. `format-table -auto` probably looks awful. I get a tonne of results with that query fyi. I think that value is in bytes? You are looking for something with more than 5k?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this query and it should run as you have it written. `Format-Table` would be making for some odd output size some of those properties do not translate to string very well. Your query and selecting some specific properties yields expected results for me. 5000 is a really low number though.

```
PS C:\Users\Matt> get-wmiobject -class Win32_Process | where-object {$_.PeakWorkingSetSize -gt "5000"} | select name,processid,peakworkingsetsize 

name                                   processid peakworkingsetsize
----                                   --------- ------------------
System                                         4              15588
csrss.exe                                    580              35412
csrss.exe                                    732              47356
services.exe                                 780              11820
winlogon.exe                                 812               8832
.... output truncated.....
```

If something is still wrong I think we need to see your *expected* output to understand what is wrong.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for the help! I guess the thing that messed me up was the lack of 'format-table -property'. I actually never knew that 'select' works pretty much the same way as a table. I sincerely appreciate it!